# How Can I practically implement the FFT with size unequal to a power of two?

Tags: fft, algorithms, discrete-signals, dft

Can anybody explain how I can implement the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) of length unequal to a power of two in hardware, e.g. FPGA? What is the algorithm for this implementation?

Does anybody know about the probable chips or hardware that are currently used with the FFT length unequal to a power of two?

Comment: This is way too broad a question than can be usefully answered on this site.  The author seems to have made no effort to look for answers e.g. via Internet search before posting here.

Comment: I searched but ... there is no right way to find it. Please first search then say.

Answer (score 10):

You need to either factor your FFT size into small prime factors if possible (e.g. 2, 3, 5, 7) and then use appropriate FFT butterflies (this is what FFTW does), otherwise look at padding the FFT with zeroes up to the next power of 2.

Comment: Would padding the data with zeros affect the result of the FFT at all?

Comment: Padding with zeroes is equivalent to interpolating the output data - you get more apparent resolution but obviously there is no additional information gained.